# Making a blacklist for an user-mode MIDI Driver

Tags: driver, midi, blacklist

## EDIT

I've actually found a way to get around this, by comparing the name of the main process with text. (_T does the trick)

Now, I want _tcscmp to compare the main process name with other names in a text file (which contains blacklisted programs). How can I do that?

```
BOOL ProcessBlackList() {
    TCHAR modulename[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, modulename, MAX_PATH);
    PathStripPath(modulename);
    if (_tcscmp(modulename, _T("bannedfile.exe")) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 0x2; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your `DLLMain` or `modMessage` function could return an error when used inside the wrong process, but you cannot foce-unload a DLL from inside itself.

Comment: Well, CoolSoft VirtualMIDISynth already implements something like that, so it should be possible.